# unable to save the input of the value

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, unable to import `body` object in another component?

Could you please help me in importing the body object in the compose component. I'm unable to display the content of the body.

Comment: Hi Chandan, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have provided `value` and `onChange` here,

```
<Editor label='Body' name="body" value={this.state.body} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
```

But in `Editor` component you have **not** provided `value` and `onChange` to `ReactQuill`, you should do this,

```
<ReactQuill
   theme='snow'
   modules={this.modules}
   formats={this.formats}   
   className='Editor'
   value={this.props.value}        // provide value passed as props from parent component
   onChange={this.props.onChange}  // provide onChange passed as props from parent component 
/>
```

**Note:** I think you should have separate change handler for your `Editor` component, because [`ReactQuill`](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) directly provides value on change.

```
<Editor label='Body' name="body" value={this.state.body} onChange={this.changeBodyHandler}/>
```

And the handler should be this,

```
changeBodyHandler = (value) => {
   this.setState({
      body: value
   })
}
```

[Simplified Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-36ufxz)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199822/discussion-on-answer-by-ravibagul91-unable-to-save-the-input-of-the-body-value).

Comment: @ravibagul91 - hi, can we reuse the respective component for reply and forward option? if yes, then i couldn't able to retrieve the code in reply component.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
changeBodyHandler = (e) => {
   this.setState({
      body: e.target.value
   })
}
```

Comment: Nope... still not getting body’s value